# why my program "creating index" doesn't work?

Tags: c, file, loops, pointers

I am coding a program which takes a text file as an input, makes the index of the words of it and prints the output(the index) in a file and in the screen. I coded as below and **tried much to spot the problem or at least narrow it down, but I couldn't.** If anyone can help or spots a problem in syntax or the logic of the code, I would be happy to know.

```
void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   
    //clearscreen
    clrscr();

//if arguments are less that default of the program
if (argc < 2) 
{
    cout << "You should've input 3 arguments." ;
    return;
}

//opening the input file and defining a pointer which points to it as argv[1]
FILE *fPtr = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

//defining a 2D array to hold maximum to 200 words holding maximum to 20 characters
char words[200][20];

//initializing words 2D array with zero ASCII
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        words[i][j] = 255;

//defining an 2D whi array which is supposed to show how many times words are placed in which lines in a defined layout
//it holds maximum to 200 words holding maximum 100 sentences
int index[200][100];

//initializing the index 2D array with zero ASCII
for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        index[i][j] = 0;

//this array of characters max to 2000 is supposed to hold each line which is gotten with fgets
char buff[2000];

//initializing the buff array with zero ASCII
for(i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    buff[i] = 0;

//the max of the words used in the source file is 200. but this valuable named as 'last' says how many words are used in this source file
//its initalized as no words is held
int last = 0;

//defining a pointer to char of punctuation mark characters. all ASCII codes expect for a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9 and newline
char *punc;

//initializing punctuation marks array
for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    if(i == 10)
        continue;
    if(i >= '0' && i <= '9')
        continue;
    if(i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')
        continue;
    if(i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z')
        continue;
    char *string = (char *) &i;
    strncat(punc, string, 1);
}

//how many lines is read from the source file
int lineread = 0;

//a word which the processes are done on that
char *word;

//one line read
while( fgets(buff, 1999, fPtr) != NULL)
{
    //how many words is read from the source file in the current line
    int wordread = 0;

    word = strtok(buff, punc);

    //one word read
    while( word != NULL)
    {
        //sorting
        int k = 0;
        while(strcmp(word, words[k])> 0)
            k++;
        if(strcmp(word, words[k]))
        {

            for(int l = last; l >= 0; l--)
            {
                strcpy(words[l + 1],words[l]);
                for(int o = 0; o <= lineread; o++)
                    index[l + 1][o] = index[l][o];
            }
            last++;
            strcpy(words[k],word);
            for(l = 0; l <= lineread; l++)
                index[k][l] = 0;
        }
        index[k][lineread]++;
        wordread++;//go to next word
        word = strtok(NULL, punc);
    }
    lineread++;//go to next line
}
//closing the input file
fclose(fPtr);

//opening the output file and defining a pointer which points to it as argv[2]
FILE *fPtr2 = fopen(argv[2], "w+");

//showing the index in cmd
for(i = 0; i <= last; i++)
{   
    printf("%-20s" , words[i]);
    fprinf(fPtr2, "%-20s" , words[i]);
    int m = 0;
    for(j = 0; j <= lineread; j++)
    {
        if(m)
        {
            printf("%c", ',');
            fprintf(fPtr2, "%c", ',');
        }
        if(index[i][j])
        {
            printf("%i", j + 1);
            fprintf(fPtr2, "%i" ,j + 1);
        }
        if(index[i][j] > 1)
        {       
            printf("(%i)", index[i][j]);
            fprintf(fPtr2, "(%i)", index[i][j]);
                m = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fprintf(fPtr2, "\n");
}

//closing the output file
fclose(fPtr);
}
```

now it errors as Abnormal program termination NULL pointer assignment. I have to use turbo c and I use DOS SHELL. there's a file names as "input.txt" in resourse. and in DOS SHELL I write this:

```
programname.exe input.txt output.txt
```

and my desired output if input.txt is this:

```
hello. hello.
how are
you? hello.

desired output:

hello                   1(2),3           //2 times in line 2, 1 time in line 1
how                     2                //1 time in line 2
are                     2               //1 time in line 2
you                     3               //1 time in line 3
```

Comment: I see you define `char * punc`, but it is uninitialized headed into the next loop, where it is used... shouldn't it be initialized to point to some memory?

Comment: no that part works correctly. I'd tested this part before.

Comment: Also, you have `words`, `index`, and `buff` all "initialized with zero ASCII", with the first one setting everything to 255, and the others setting everything to 0. I take it you meant to be doing the same thing to all three.

Comment: I really don't know why does this work and I have just 1 hour to give in this. please please help if possible.

Comment: It'd also help if we could see one of the "wrong outputs" and the corresponding "right output"

Comment: no if you read the loop containing fgets, you will come to know why I initialized words array with 255. coz I needed that each word added from from the file to be less than each block of the words array.

Comment: I am really thankful. ok, I edit the questions with outputs.

Comment: I am waiting for your helps. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also not sure about - `words[i][j] = 255;` this won't work nicely with strcpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with this line:

```
while(strcmp(word, words[k])> 0)
```

Because `index` is initialized as `255` and according to the algorithm `strcmp` works based on, for first word the code works right and puts it in `word[0]` but for the second word it won't work properly.for example:

```
first word: Kittens
second word: Biscuits
```

first `strcmp` compares `Kittens` with `255 ASCII code`. the result is that `Kitten` is smaller and the process will put it in `word[0]`. But for the second word, `strcmp` compares `Biscuits` with `Kittens` and the result is that `Kittens` is bigger and program will go through another blocks of `word[]` which in not wanted. the program will be fixed by initializing `word[]` to `0` and using this code instead of that which is first mentioned:

```
while(strcmp(word, words[k])> 0)
```